# How to select multiple files in open dialog box in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, fileopendialog

These are the two methods in Inno Setup to show file selection dialog,

Wizard Page Method:

```pascal
[Code]
Var
  PageFileDialog: TInputFileWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  PageFileDialog:= CreateInputFilePage(
    wpWelcome, 
    'Title 1', 
    'Title 2', 
    'Title 3'); 
 
  PageFileDialog:= PageFileDialog.Edits[PageFileDialog.Add('', 'Text file (*.txt)|*.txt', '.txt')];
end;
```

Direct Open Dialog,

```pascal
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
    FileName: string;
begin
    FileName := '';
    if GetOpenFileName('', FileName, '', 
    'Text Documents (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files|*.*', 'txt') then
    begin
       { Filename contains the selected filename }
    end;
end;
```

But these does no allow to select multiple files in the open dialog, It only selects one file. How to select multiple files?

The method in question  [Inno Setup with three destination folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657175/inno-setup-with-three-destination-folders) does not work here. It should be one textbox and browse button that can select multiple files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested with Inno Setup 6.0.5(u).  Other versions may be different.

Take a look at the `GetOpenFileNameMulti` function:
From the [documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getopenfilenamemulti):

> Description:
> Displays a dialog box that enables the user to select one or more existing file(s). Returns True if the user selected a file, False otherwise. The name of the selected file(s) is returned in the FileNameList list.
>
> Remarks:
> An example Filter: 'Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*'
>
> Example:
>
> ```pascal
> var
>   FileNameList: TStrings;
> begin
>   { Create the list }
>   FileNameList := TStringList.Create;
>   try
>     if GetOpenFileNameMulti('', FileNameList, '',
>        'Text Documents (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files|*.*', 'txt') then
>     begin
>       { Successful; user clicked OK }
>       { FileNameList contains the selected filename(s) }
>     end;
>   finally
>     FileNameList.Free;
>   end;
> end;
> ```